# Wordpress custom text fields

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm kinda new to wordpress. How can I make these three fields:

[image]

editable using wordpress?

I'd rather not do it by creating wordpress posts and assigning a category, what is the "right" way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: if this is just on your contact page you can use [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), but if you want to show it site wide (in your footer for example) you would use the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). There are plugins to handle this as well, my favorite being [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: as @doublesharp has noted , the best way to do this would be with a custom meta box and custom fields .

Comment: Yup I tried out Advanced Custom Fields and it was clearly the way to go. Thanks! :D